# div getting line-height from parent always

Tags: html, css

Consider this:

```
<div id="parent">
    This is some text
    <div id="child">
        <ul><li><a href="#">test</a></li></ul>
        This some other text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{line-height: 55px}
#child{line-height: 20px}
ul{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none}
```

Problem: Ths links in div "child" not getting line-height:20px. It's getting line-height:55px from the main "parent" div. I tried putting !important, but does not work.

But when I put line-height to the li, then it works.

Comment: Works fine for me?  Which browser is this in?

Comment: Does indeed work fine.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some details. the question is edited

Answer (score 4):

Who said it's not getting the `line-height: 22px;`? The `line-height` of the parent element pushes `#child` down.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K88pn/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K88pn/1/) *(When child Inherits the parents `line-height`)*

---

If you are wishing the child element to stick the parents text, than I think you are not using the right property, you should use `padding-top` instead.

```
#parent {
    padding-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
#child {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K88pn/2/)

---

**After you edited your question**, it still works as expected, I don't know what makes you think it doesn't work. In the below example, I've deliberately added more `line-height` for demo purpose.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/usm33/) *(After you edited your question)*

```
#parent {
    line-height: 55px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#child {
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

---

If this is all what you got in your document, than you are wrong, it it still doesn't work in any case, than specificity might be an issue for you which I cannot bet on, as I don't have sufficient resources from your side.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some details. the question is edited